# Python requests: Using response.raw as stdin of a subprocess

Tags: python, python-requests, subprocess

I just want to use `requests.get()` to download some file (it may be very huge) and then pass the data to the `stdin` of another process created by `subprocess.Popen`. The example code is

```
In [137]: r = requests.get('http://www.google.com', stream=True)
In [138]: p = subprocess.Popen(['wc'], stdin=r.raw, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
In [139]: p.communicate()
```

This doesn't work well. Two problems:

1. It takes very long time to complete even the network is good. The reason is the subprocess try to read some data until timeout.

   ```
   $ sudo strace -p 181082                                                                                                             
   strace: Process 181082 attached
   read(0, "", 16384)                      = 0   <== Here, it takes very long time.
   fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
   write(1, "      0       0       0\n", 24) = 24
   close(0)                                = 0
   close(1)                                = 0
   close(2)                                = 0
   exit_group(0)                           = ?
   +++ exited with 0 +++
   ```
2. The data passed to `stdin` isn't correct. As you can see that the output of `wc` is `0 0 0`.

I tried to set `r.raw.decode_content = True`, but doesn't help.

NOTE: Because the file downloaded by `get` may be very huge, using `r.content` etc. is not acceptable.

NOTE: I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to just use [response.iter_content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) to incrementally read the response body and write it to the process's stdin in chunks:

```
import requests
import subprocess
r = requests.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com', stream=True)
r.raise_for_status()
p = subprocess.Popen(['wc'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for chunk in r.iter_content(2048):
    p.stdin.write(chunk)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print("wc output:", stdout)
```

This way you're not using any file-like object from `requests`, but you don't need one. Observe that `Popen` already creates a file-like object (namely a pipe) accessible as `process.stdin` which you can use to pass data to the process in real time as it arrives.

It's not immediately obvious that `p.communicate()` does two things here:

- closes the standard input pipe without writing any more data to it, telling `wc` that we're done with writing and it can output the counts;
- then reads everything from the stdout pipe into a variable.

*Note:* `wc` fits well here because it consumes the whole `stdin` before printing to `stdout`, but this approach may deadlock if your process tries writing to `stdout` before `stdin` is fully consumed. In this case, the program could would freeze on `p.stdin.write` while the process waits for Python to read from `p.stdout`.

In order to handle that properly, you'd need to write separate threads for reading and writing. `communicate()` does that for you, but it only accepts input as a string, not a stream or generator. Another alternative would be to have the process write to a tempfile rather than a pipe.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My real problem is to download a tar file and pass it to `tar tv` command. In this case, the loop of write to `stdin` deadlocked. I will try to use a temp file to resolve this.